# Bootstrap tab for buttons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I have a sign up page divided into two sections. I just want to show each section content hiding in current page when someone click these major buttons. The concept is similar to bootstrap tabs, but I'm not using tabs here. These are simple bootstrap buttons. I tried to play with bootstrap classes with my code but got no luck. I'm using meteor and react. 
Screenshot for the image.

["Work and Hire Buttons"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vMlz.png)

And this is my code

```
<div id="signup-top-btn">
    <div id="myTabs" role="tablist">
      <div className="col-xs-6 signup-work-btn">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-block blue-btn active-btn"
          data-toggle="tab"
        >
          Work
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-6 signup-hire-btn">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-block blue-btn"
          data-toggle="tab" data-target="#employer-signup"
        >
          Hire
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why would you create your own tabs with buttons? why not use Bootstrap tabs and style those.. Like: http://www.bootply.com/CrAGi1Btxj

Comment: This is I want ! Thanks

Comment: Np, I'v made an answer instead of a comment, please accept this answer and close the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the Bootstrap tabs, and style those like:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#work" role="tab" class="btn btn-block blue-btn active-btn" data-toggle="tab">Work</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#hire" class="btn btn-primary btn-block blue-btn" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Hire</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="work">...my working tab</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="hire">...my hiring tab</div>
  </div>
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/CrAGi1Btxj

Answer (score 0):

You can always use JavaScript:

```
$('button[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.nav-tabs').find('a[href="' + $(this).data('target') + '"]').click();
});
```